# Cannot get code to retrieve exponent of Input(), AND determine if it's a number or a letter to output proper comment

Tags: python, python-3.x

UPDATE: I found out that 'break' is incorrect for me to use here, and I should be using 'sysexit()' instead.

```
Value = input("Put a number in here, watch it multiply itself! [q to quit]: ")
try:
    Value == 'q'
    sysexit()
except Value == ValueError:
    print("Excuse me; I don't think that's a number. Please try again!")
except request == int(Value):
    print(value + " multipled by " + value + "is " (value * value))
```

And the code loads now, but it won't accept any inputs, giving me two errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "More if then practice", line 4, in <module>
sysexit()
NameError: name 'sysexit' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "More if then practice", line 5, in <module>
    except Value == ValueError:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

***Repl Closed***
```

Still not sure what to do, however.
I'm learning Python using o'reilly's series of books, and there's an demonstration of how to use a "While True" loop, to check an input() variable

```
while True: 
    value = input(" Integer, please [q to quit]: ") 
    if value = = 'q':     # quit function 
       break
    number = int( value)
  if number % 2 = = 0: # an even number
    continue 
print( number, "squared is", number* number)
```

(Bill Lubanovic. Introducing Python - O'Reilly Media, Inc..)

For exercise purposes, I have been trying to make this code capable of the following:

> q for quit ability
>
> detecting whether the input is a number or letter/other
>
> multiplying both odd and even numbers.

I had a version I wrote last night that would at least run, but wouldn't multiply, and this morning I found a StackOverflow post where a "try/except" argument was provided with two exceptions. Now my code looks like this:

```
Value = input("Put a number in here, watch it multiply itself! [q to quit]: ")
try:
    Value == 'q'
    break
except ValueError:
    print("Excuse me; I don't think that's a number. Please try again!")
except request == int(Value):

print(value + " multipled by " + value + "is " (value * value))
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
line 4
break
^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

I've shifted code around, used different a while true/for loop instead, and double checked syntax from other posts on the internet, and believe I'm using it correctly here.

```
Value = input("Put a number in here, watch it multiply itself! [q to quit]: ")
try:
    Value == 'q'
    break
except ValueError:
    print("Excuse me; I don't think that's a number. Please try again!")
except request == int(Value):

print(value + " multipled by " + value + "is " (value * value))
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
line 4
break
^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Expected: To be executable to where I can meet the standards listed in the initial Summary

Actual: Crashes due to the error listed in the Summary and Code sections.

Comment: What do you expect that `break` to do?

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here... 1. There is no loop so what are you breaking? 2. `Value == 'q'` will do nothing in your code. It will silently evaluate to either True or False then continue to the next line without doing anything. 3. `except request == int(value)` This is not valid. The use of `try` and `except` is to catch exceptions. It should be formatted like `except ExceptionName:` or `except ExceptionName as e:`. 4. Even if the exception syntax was right in (3), the indentation is wrong when you try to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your original code:

```
while True: 
    value = input(" Integer, please [q to quit]: ") 
    if value = = 'q':     # quit function 
       break
    number = int( value)
  if number % 2 = = 0: # an even number
    continue 
print( number, "squared is", number* number)
```

Sources of error could include

- Indentation is off (important in python)

  - Your `if` statements need to be the same level
  - Your `break` needs another space
  - Your `print()` needs to be indented inside loop
- `= =` needs to be `==` (no spaces, since this will cause a `SyntaxError`)
- No error checking (I believe this is your intent with "detecting whether the input is a number or letter/other")

To include your requirements of:

> multiplying both odd and even numbers.

Simply take out your second `if` statement.

> q for quit ability

Simply fix `= =` -> `==`

> detecting whether the input is a number or letter/other

Try to cast the input to `int()` and if it throws a `ValueError` exception, it is "other"

Putting it together:

```
while True:
    value = input("Please enter an integer (q to quit):\n>>>") # I like aesthetic prompts
    if value == 'q': # quit function
        break
    try:
        number = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a valid number")
        continue
    print("{} squared is {}".format(number, number ** 2))
```

With sample output:

```
Please enter an integer (q to quit):
>>>5
5 squared is 25
Please enter an integer (q to quit):
>>>16
16 squared is 256
Please enter an integer (q to quit):
>>>stop
That's not a valid number
Please enter an integer (q to quit):
>>>6
6 squared is 36
Please enter an integer (q to quit):
>>>q

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hope this helps, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: This ran perfectly! Thank you so much for such a concise and speedy answer, and the warm welcome. :)

I do like your print() function's syntax a lot more, but I'm curious as to why I couldn't get mine to work even after putting it back in the loop. What would be the proper format for the way that I was doing it, just so I can bridge the logic gap in my head?

Comment: @BreakfastXO Your second example doesn't make sense for several reasons. I think you are confusing `if` statements with `try` statements (perhaps from some other language, idk). Also, the `break` statement is *only* used to end a `for` or `while` loop prematurely, which is why the interpreter got confused and told you `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`, since your code had neither a `for` or `while` loop. I'm not sure how you intend me to explain a proper format for it though, since you would arrive at the same solution (or one that is very similar) as the one I already posted after edits.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I should have mentioned I entirely deviated away from my edited code now at the beginning of my post, and I followed your format instead.

Where you suggested:
    print("{} squared is {}".format(number, number ** 2))

I attempted:
    print(value + " multipled by " + value + "is " (value * value))

I was just curious what difference I could make to my format to make it work, just so I understand how python works a bit better. I'll be using your format from here on out, though.

Comment: @BreakfastXO Oh I see. You just need to change the numbers into their representations in string format. Running `value = 5`;`print(str(value) + " multipled by " + str(value) + " is " + str(value * value))` works for me!

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense, as I wasn't converting the output into a string. Thank you kindly! : )